# How can I do this curl request in a Laravel test?

Tags: php, laravel, curl, request

I'm working under TDD in a Laravel 8 project, I'm making a token generation test, a client has to send its user and password and then my app has to generate the token and send it back. I'm making the test for this, but I don't know how to make the request, the request that I want to do is something like this curl:

```
curl -X "GET" https://127.0.0.1:8000/token
-H "Accept: application/json"
-H "Content-Type: appication/json"
-u "JohnDoe:johndoeiscool123"
```

As you can see, there are some headers and there is one `-u` field, I don't know how to set this `-u` in a Laravel test, I have this:

```
public function test_getting_token() {

    $response = $this->get("/token", [
  
        "Accept: application/json",
        "Content-Type: application/json",

    ]);

}
```

Can someone help me please?

Comment: Take a look at https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/http-tests#customizing-request-headers and also you can use `getJson` instead of `get` and then you don't need to send the `Accept` header (the content type header is also not necessary for get requests at all)

Comment: I don't recall using basic auth from laravel, but if options are passed as is, then `$this->getJson('/token',['auth' => ['JohnDoe', 'johndoeiscool123']])` should work